# Coding database connectors

Tags: python, django, database, database-connection

I do not know whether its a correct forum to ask, I just wanted to know that **"Can we code Database connectors yourself?"** I am working on a framework which does not support my Database.

I thought maybe I need to code it myself? Is it Possible? 
By the way, I am **working in python**.

> Framework: django
>
> DB: HP Vertica

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the names of framework and database? Community is better able to help when specific details are provided.

Comment: Framework: Django; DB: HP Vertica